# Using a Variant Array in a loop (error 13 type mismatch)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, ms-office

I'm doing a for loop and need to use a Variant Array type, but i'm getting Error 13 (type mismatch). I want k to be 3, 4 and 5 for the 1st value, and so on (according to variable inspection below). I just don't know how to make vba read the array. I've tried using `tsperiodo(i)(j)` but it hasn't worked either.

Here is the variant array:

```
ReDim ocup(1 To numDis, 1 To numSalas) As Variant

For i = 1 To numDis
    For j = 1 To numSalas
        If capacidadeSalas(j) - alunos(i) >= 0 Then
        ocup(i, j) = 1
        End If
    Next
Next    

ReDim tsPeriodo(1 To numDis) As Variant

For i = 1 To numDis
    tsPeriodo(i) = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=ROW(" & tsInicio(i) & ":" & tsFim(i) & ")"))
Next
```

and here is where i want to use it:

```
For i = 1 To ocup(numDis, 1)
    For j = 1 To ocup(1, numSalas)
        For k = 1 To tsPeriodo(i)  'this is where im getting error 13
            variable = "x_" & i & "_" & j & "_" & k
        Next
    Next
Next
```

[variable inspection for the tsperiodo(i)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNFZ9.png)

Comment: what version of Excel are you using ? French ? what is `For i = 1 To ocup(numDis, 1)` suppost to be ?

Comment: I'm using excel 2016 in portuguese! "ocup" it's a variat array too, but that's working properly, i will edit the main post to insert it in the code.

Comment: You never show how `tsInicio(i)` and `tsFim(i)` are instantiated. `Evaluate("=ROW(" & tsInicio(i) & ":" & tsFim(i) & ")")` will just return the a number not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding deeply what you are trying to achieve, obviously each element of tsPeriodo is an variant/array itself, so you end up with some kind of a (non-standard) 2D array. To catch all the elements inside it in your loop, you can try this:

```
Dim k, l
For Each k In tsPeriodo
    For Each l In k
      ' doSomething, i.e.
      variable = "x_" & i & "_" & j & "_" & l

    Next
Next
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Is there another way to retrieve the variables from a variant type array or this is the only one?

Comment: Usually you can also index it in the usual way, but you need to know the number of dimensions, the size of each element, etc. With `For Each` you  need less prior knowledge.